# OnSwipe conflicting with other views in Motionlayout scene transition

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-motionlayout, android-gesture

I have a custum view in the background and a motion layout on top of that. Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".ui.DetailFragment">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.example.complexmotion.customui.DownloadIcon
            android:id="@+id/customIcon"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layoutDescription="@xml/fragment_detail_scene">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="@drawable/background_card_white"
                android:translationZ="5dp"
                app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/guideline" />

            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_20dp"
                android:elevation="@dimen/_20dp"
                android:translationZ="7dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/guideline"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/guideline">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:id="@+id/cl_for_text"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/fileName"
                        style="@style/textStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
                        android:text="@string/file_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/downloadedFileName"
                        style="@style/textStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:text="@string/file_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey"

                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/fileName" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/status"
                        style="@style/textStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20dp"
                        android:text="@string/status"
                        android:textColor="@color/grey"

                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/downloadedFileName" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/downloadStatus"
                        style="@style/textStyle"
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/tealBlue"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/downloadedFileName"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/status" />

                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</layout>
```

I have a motion scene where I want to play a transtion only when my recycler view is swiped up or down. So my motion scene looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start"/>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:translationZ="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cardView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
            android:translationZ="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/recyclerView" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@id/end"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start"
        app:duration="1000">
        <OnSwipe app:touchAnchorId="@id/recyclerView" />
        <KeyFrameSet>
            <KeyPosition
                app:framePosition="45"
                app:keyPositionType="parentRelative"
                app:motionTarget="@id/cardView"
                app:percentY="0.1" />
        </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>
</MotionScene>
```

I also want user to interact with my custom view. But onSwipe restricts it from happening. If I remove onSwipe inside the transition then user can interact [Screen shot of a user interacting with the background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6y5Y.png) but my transition won't play smoothly.
[Complete project on git](https://github.com/Abh1shekTyagi/MotionAndRecyclerView)

I tried doing it setting progress of the motionlayout but it's not smooth, I also tried

```
limitBoundsTo
```

that also not working the way I desire.